# Nautilus does not show the left bar, how do I turn it back on?

Tags: nautilus

When I open nautilus does not open the left bar where it says computer and down markers such as music, documents, videos, downloads. I reinstalled nautilus from the synaptic package manager but nothing happened. What I can do to make that bar visible again?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Just press <kbd>F9</kbd> when you open nautilus.

Another way to do this is

Click on '**view**' then check the '*side pane*' option.

Answer (score 6):

You can activate or deactivate the sidebar simply by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>. You can also go up to the global menu, then select *View* → *Sidebar* → *Show sidebar*.

Answer (score 5):

Just press <kbd>F9</kbd> or if you like it the 'mouse' way, jut select 'Side Pane' from the 'View' menu.

Answer (score 5):

Open Files and then in the left side of the top bar select Files which will present a dropdown menu from which you can select Sidebar.

[image]
An alternative (reminder courtesy of @PRATAP) is to press <kbd>F9</kbd> on opening Nautilus,