# Ubuntu 11.10 Home folder places bar missing

Tags: 11.10, home-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nautilus does not show the left bar, how do I turn it back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139058/nautilus-does-not-show-the-left-bar-how-do-i-turn-it-back-on)

Today I noticed that my "places" are missing when I open Home Folder. I should see it if I open any folder.

[image: http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Ubuntuhomefolder-640x480.jpg]

I don't know how it's called, you can see on this picture. the left side bar, that's missing. Can you help me how to retrieve it

Comment: Does pressing F9 bring it back?

Comment: haha so easy, didn't know that. thank you man :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your file manager, press <kbd>F9</kbd>
 or
go through menu View--->Sidebar--->Show Sidebar and check to enable it.

[image: That way]