# Nautilus left pane sidebar not showing

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nautilus does not show the left bar, how do I turn it back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139058/nautilus-does-not-show-the-left-bar-how-do-i-turn-it-back-on)

In Ubuntu 12.04, my Nautilus sidebar is not visible. How can I restore it?