# Can't see my 'other Locations' option in Ubuntu 18.04 desktop

Tags: files, filesystem, filemanager

I have 3 partitions on my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. It was good until yesterday. But don't know what happened. I Can't see 'Other Options' in the file manager when I open it. Looks weird. the file manager looks different than it usually used to look.[Here is my the screenshot I have uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Jdq.png).
It doesn't have a left-side panel which it usually contains all the list which is in the middle.
Please Help me.

Comment: sorry, It didn't work.

Comment: Okay, I found your answer. You can press F9 to toggle the side bar. https://askubuntu.com/questions/139058/nautilus-does-not-show-the-left-bar-how-do-i-turn-it-back-on

Comment: Also, on unity you can click on "files" that is on the global menu or dash bar at the top of the screen. From the dropdown menu, you can click on "sidebar".